# Number of ways to achieve first passage in coin toss

Tags: probability

Tossing a coin results either head (H) or tail (T). Now toss a coin $n$ times, and define $M(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where 
$$
X_i = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } ith \text{ toss is Head}\\
-1 & \text{if } ith \text{ toss is Tail}
\end{cases}
$$ 
To achieve $M(n) = 1$, $n$ must be an odd integer. My questions is how many different routines to have $M(n) = 1$ while $M(m) < 1$ for all $1 \le m \lt n$? Namely, at the $n$th toss, it is the first time for $M$ to become 1.

For example, when $n=5$, there are only two possible ways: TTHHH and THTHH.

Comment: This is related to the [*Catalan number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics).

Comment: @SangchulLee thanks for telling me this.